# How to scroll to a row in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scrollbar

I have a table view which has 1112 rows, only 18 rows are visible at time. Everything is fine, when i am scrolling through table,i could see all other row.
Now, in the same view, i am having a UItextBox and when user enters any value say 'some Id' in the text box, i go and update my core data to new values and get the updated data again from core data and reload the table.

I have requirement that when i reload the table, table should automatically scroll to latest updated row.

How should i scroll to the row which has the value entered in textbox. I don't have the index as i am not selecting any row.

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) 
{ 
cell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ; 
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 }
 OObieDetail *oobe =[oobeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [cell setOrderObj:oobe];
 return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Pls  add your cellforrowindex code for reference.

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
 if (cell == nil)
 {
         cell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    
    OObieDetail *oobe =[oobeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [cell setOrderObj:oobe];
    return cell;
}

Comment: is UItextBox above in tableview or in cell ?, if you are searching values based on id use nspredicate to search object and get index of object from array

Comment: UITextBox is above tableview. I am searching value based on id and then using coredata method to update the value in core date and then reload the table.